# fstream never reaches eof

Tags: c++

I'm writing a translator for a lisp-like language.  The input file is read in token-by-token.  I'm controlling it with an `std::fstream` at the top level like this:

```
...
std::fstream fin(path, std::fstream::in);
symtable table; // aliased map<>

while (!fin.eof()) {
   try {
      std::cout << "file still has contents!" << std::endl;
      parse(fin, symbol_table);
   } catch (LexException le) {
      std::cout << le.what() << std::endl;
   } catch (ParseException pe) {
      std::cout << le.what() << std::endl;
   }
}
```

In my lexer, I handle leading whitespace and count lines like this:

```
char ch;
while (fin >> std::noskipws >> ch) {
   if (ch == '\n') {
      line++;
      continue;
   } else if (isspace(ch)) {
      continue;
   }

   break;
}    

if (ch <= 32) {
    // return the "empty" token, as there's nothing grab from the file anymore
    return std::make_tuple("", -500);
}
// The rest is code which builds a token
```

This is also the area where things are getting weird.

When I pass in this as an input: `()`, it's fine, and produces exactly what I want.

When I pass in this as input: `(`, I get an infinite loop.

When I debug, I see that `(` is indeed read in as a token.  My code then goes through, reads in the newline that Vim inserts, and then enters an infinite loop because `EOF` is never read.  Furthermore, my `std::cout` statement is never printed.

Why is this the case?  Why does it work just fine with `()`, but fails on `(`?

**Edit:** The full source is too large for one post, [but is available on my github](https://github.com/cartermp/compiler).

Comment: If your program is not too large, please post the complete program. If it is, post all the functions in which `fin` is used.

Comment: Unfortunately it's too large.  [The latest is up on my Github](https://github.com/cartermp/compiler).